# Floor jack tonnage vs vehicle weight

Tags: jack

How do you decide what tonnage floor jack do you need vs the weight of the vehicle? I am asking because it is not as straightforward as having a jack that can support the total weight of the vehicle, that would be an overkill. I guess that, when jacking, you do not rest the whole weight on the jack, only some, as the other 3 wheels are usually either grounded or on a jackstand. So, for example, if my truck weighs 4500 lbs, would a 2T jack be fine or go with 2.5, which would be more than the weight of the truck (as though I am lifting the whole weight, which I am not). I am asking because I would like to go with a more minimalistic jack, as bigger ones are heavier and take more space.

Or is jack tonnage specified relative to the weight of the vehicle, not the actual weight that the jack is resisting?

Comment: If you lift the whole front of the vehicle that might be more than half the total weight.

Comment: 4500lbs is 2 tons, to within 2%... The 2T jack will be fine for lifting one end at a time.

Comment: "having a jack that can support the total weight of the vehicle, that would be an overkill" - I would choose overkill over being killed any day!

Comment: Google search; Choose the Right Capacity
1-Find your gross vehicle weight and front and rear weights on the sticker inside your door or in your vehicle's manual.
2-Be sure to get more weight lifting capacity than you need.
3-Don't go overboard – the higher the capacity, the slower and heavier the jack.